Есть ли ошибки в этих двух предложениях (из статьи о правильном переводе художественного текста)
Статья посвящена теме переводов сонетов 11 и 77 английского поэта и драматурга и написана автором, который считает себя специалистом в этой области, например: "Нам, исследователям творческого наследия Уильяма Шекспира доподлинно известно..."
Но читать статью не очень комфортно вследствие недостаточной грамотности текста, так что и смысл не всегда понятен, например:
Не зависимо от даты написания, и порядка нумерации сонетов, учёные смогли определить основную подгруппу "брачных сонетов". И сделать заключительные выводы, что "достоверно и правильно, что первые семнадцать сонетов, в которых поэт призывает своего молодого друга жениться, чтобы увековечить свою красоту, имеют тематическое единство", что определило место сонета 11, как основной связующей части всей подгруппы состоящей из 17-ти сонетов, названных критиками, как сонеты "о продолжении рода".
Есть ли ошибки в двух приведенных предложениях (стиль, грамматика, орфография, пунктуация) и как их исправить? Меня интересует прежде всего правильная запись текста, чтобы логику рассуждения можно было понять.
P. S. Хотелось бы доверять автору, но такое правописание ставит под сомнение  достоверность  информации в статье. Можно ли рассуждать о правильности перевода, если собственный текст не выглядит правильным?
